# How can I find out what is the name of the main form object

Tags: c#, winforms

Pretty short question: How can I find out what is the name of the main form object?

I want to know this, because I want to call some of the functions or get some of the variables from the main form object. Of course, I need to know the name of the object to do so (is this a good idea?).

Comment: Find the name or the instance?

Comment: Are you asking about determining the name (or instance) programmatically at runtime or while you are coding during development?

Comment: Wait.. What are you trying to do? You say you want to get the name while developing. Don't you know the name of your main form? The main form is the one started by `Application.Run`...

Comment: The line where the form gets enables is this: "Application.Run(new MainForm());"...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property to get all open forms, and the get the Name from that. As noted by DaveShaw in the comments, the main form is often the first one in the list, at index 0.

```
string name = Application.OpenForms[0].Name;
```

Comment: The Main Form is often at index `0`.

Comment: Also, I should have said "at least it is in my application's codebase"

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean?
1. the name of the type:

```
   class form1
   {}
```

and it returns "form1"
2.the name of the object

```
   class form1
   {}
   form1 obj
```

and it returns "obj"